# Creating a summary sheet from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

**PROBLEM**

I want to iterate through all sheets and create a summary sheet. I have a dynamic column, whereas, some header is on `COLUMN X` while some on `COLUMN AG`.

So instead of selecting the specific column, I decided to get the specific header name in order to address that issue.

However, I can't seem to progress on my code since I don't know how to loop all throughout the sheets, get the column then add it to the summary.

**CODE**

```
Public Sub forSummary()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range, rng1 As Range

'~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JAN 6")

With ws
    '~~> Find the cell which has the name
    Set aCell = .Range("A1:BA1").Find("TOTAL OUT")

    '~~> If the cell is found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Get the last row in that column and check if the last row is > 1
        lRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If lRow > 1 Then
            '~~> Set your Range
            Set rng1 = .Range(aCell.Offset(1), .Cells(lRow, aCell.Column))
            '~~> This will give you the address
            rng1.Select
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: do you need VBA at all? At least in Libreoffice, with Sheet1, Sheet2 trough Sheet 5, you can write ```=SUM(Sheet2.A1:B1:Sheet5.A1:B1)``` to sum up A1:B1 in all sheets between 2nd and 5th. Also: Just found a counterpart in Excel: https://superuser.com/questions/331252/reference-a-range-of-cells-on-all-sheets-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are setting your `ws` to a specific sheet. Instead, loop through the worksheet collection and do your work that way.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, tempRng As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set tempRng = ws.Range()    'Set your range you need for your summary page

    ' Code to perform actions with your range

    Set tempRng = Nothing

Next ws
```

Comment: Yeah, I just thought of that lol. How do I append each sheet to the summary then?